Best way to calculate boolean matrix multiplication in numpy
I want calculate the matrix product of a boolean array with its transpose:
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0]], dtype=bool)

What's the best/fastest way of doing this?
I made several attemps:

Attempt 1
out1 = np.matmul(a, a.T)
print(out1)


[[ True  True] [ True  True]]

Just applying np.matmul doesn't work because of overflow.

Attempt 2
So I came up with the idea of passing a np.uint64 output array to the function: Doesn't work either. Seems like the sum is calculated with bools, then casted to uint64.
out2 = np.zeros((2, 2), dtype=np.uint64)
np.matmul(a, a.T, out=out2)
print(out2)


[[1 1] [1 1]]


Attempt 3
Manually calculating the row*column product then calling sum works: But it takes way too much memory, as it stores all product results before summing them up.
out3 = (a[None,:, :] * a[:, None, :]).sum(axis=-1)
print(out3)


[[2 1] [1 2]]


Attempt 4
So I tried casting the array before calculation: Does work too. But casting the input array takes 64 times of the memory and I guess that the multiplication takes more time if conducted with uint64 compared to two booleans.
out4 = np.matmul(a.astype(np.uint64), a.T)
print(out4)


[[2 1] [1 2]]


Is there any better solution for this problem that I might have overseen?

It seems like you want to multiply as integers, right? Why not a.astype(np.uint8) @ a.T.

Someone correct me, if I'm wrong, but isn't the multiplication of two boolean faster than multiplication of a boolean and an integer, as it is simply an bitwise_or operation? At least this way takes more memory as the full input array first needs to be converted. But the basic problem is that products are all summed up in the same type as as the "largest" input type. uint8 might still not be large enough for the result.

What overflow are you complaining about? Using np.logical_and for the broadcasted multiply step, and np.logical_or.reduce for the sum step, does the same thing as matmul or einsum. Your [2,1]... answer isn't a boolean result; it's integer matmul.

The "best" way would be to use the dtype argument of matmul, like np.matmul(a, a.T, dtype=np.uint32). If you want to use logical operations, you may need to use numba or something. I don't think there is a way to make matmul use logical operations for this case.

@Hackster "Someone correct me, if I'm wrong, but isn't the multiplication of two boolean [...] an bitwise_or operation?" -> no, it's a bitwise AND. See my answer below. Your calculation was correct and should result in all True.

The main problem here is that the addition and multiplication of boolean values is not defined the way you think so is matrix multiplication of booleans. This part is just pure math : fields operations are defined as mapping FxF->F, that is binary operations on well defined set. It seems what you want is not a binary operation on (closed) set (of binary numbers). This is not the standard one (and it is not composable) so you need to define it first to avoid confusion.

Because of this, it is better to either split the question in two parts (one only about this problem and one only about speed), or if you do not care about the above issue, then you just edit it to only focus about speed (just give an example of slow code and the result you want -- i.e. define your custom non-standard boolean operation -- without talking about "overflow")

There is no "overflow" in your calculation. The multiplication and addition have a different meaning with booleans.
Let's assume this other example:
a = np.array([[1, 0, 1],
              [0, 1, 0]], dtype=bool)

out1 = np.matmul(a, a.T)

array([[ True, False],
       [False,  True]])

The result is correct and is True if there is at least one of the products that is non null. Assuming i,j the coordinates, this means:
out[i,j] = a[i,0]*a[j,0] + a[i,1]*a[j,1] + a[i,2]*a[j,2]

With
booleans, * is equivalent to &, and + to |.
# product / & truth table 
np.array([False, True]) * np.array([[False], [True]])

array([[False, False],
       [False,  True]])

# sum / | truth table
np.array([False, True]) + np.array([[False], [True]])

array([[False,  True],
       [ True,  True]])

therefore, the boolean dot product is:
out[i,j] = a[i,0]&a[j,0] | a[i,1]&a[j,1] | a[i,2]&a[j,2]

In fact if you first convert to integer, you will get the same result, except with integer calculations:
np.matmul(a.astype(np.uint64), a.T)

array([[2, 0],
       [0, 1]], dtype=uint64)

# now let's convert back to bool, after the dot product
np.matmul(a.astype(np.uint64), a.T).astype(bool)

array([[ True, False],
       [False,  True]])

Now the question is: what do you need as output?
If you want integers, then first convert to integer and perform the computation. You will use more memory, but there is nothing you can do to avoid it.
If you want a boolean, then the original approach is fine. The intermediates will use less memory than an integer computation.

So, Instead of using np.matmul directly on boolean arrays, you can use the fact that boolean values can be treated as integers 0 and 1. Here’s an alternative approach that uses the np.einsum function, which allows you to specify the exact summation and multiplication behavior without intermediate storage of all the products.

a = np.array([[1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0]], dtype=bool)
result = np.einsum('ij,ik->jk', a, a)

np.einsum('ij,ik->jk', a, a) computes the product of a and its transpose without explicitly creating a large intermediate array.
i represents the rows of a.
j represents the columns of the result matrix.
k is the axis over which to sum (this is where the inner product occurs).

While the under cover details are unclear, it appears that einsum usually tries to reduce the problem to a matmul like case and use the same fast compiled BLAS code,  a.T is a view, not a copy, though matmul may have to make a contiguous copy when passing it to BLAS.  In short, it's hard to generalize speed claims without timings on realistic sized arrays.  I suspect your example times about the same as the OP's #1.

@hpaulj Yes, einsum can use BLAS but, no, einsum does not use BLAS here because BLAS only support floating-point functions. And yes it should be similar to the OP's #1 code (or at least slow anyway).

This is the most efficient technique and saves significant memory if your matrix has many zeros.
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix

a = np.array([[1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0]], dtype=bool)

# Convert to a sparse matrix
a_sparse = csr_matrix(a, dtype=np.int8)

result_sparse = a_sparse @ a_sparse.T

print(result_sparse.toarray())
'''
[[2 1]
 [1 2]]
'''


No, it is clearly not "the most efficient technique". It might be just faster, but far from being optimal. Also, please note that the result can certainly overflow float relatively-large matrices (>130x130) so one need to be careful with dtype=np.int8.
